# Снимок на динамическую вьюшку

Tags: clearcase, контроль-версий, консоль

Как подлить снимок на динамическую вьюшку через консоль администратора в ClearCase?

Answer (score 1):

- Если надо смержить, то [merge](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_merge.htm).
- Если надо просто подлить файлы на динамическую вьюху, то [checkin](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_checkin.htm).

Файлы подливаются по правилам в текущем configspec.